# Can't do json_decode when saved data by JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, php

**library address**

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

**HTML**

```
<input name="title[]" type="text" value="a1">
<input name="content[]" type="text" value="a2">
<input name="title[]" type="text" value="b1">
<input name="content[]" type="text" value="b2">
<input id="result" type="text">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var result = [];

$('[name="title[]"]'].each(function(index) {
    content = $('[name="content[]"]').eq(index).val();
    result.push({title: $(this).val(), content: content});
});

$('#result').val(JSON.stringify(result));
```

When I save it, I got this in database

`"[{\"title\":\"a\",\"content\":\"a2\"},{\"title\":\"b\",\"content\":\"b2\"}]"`

When I var_dump json_decode, I got

`string '[{"title":"a","content":"a2"},{"title":"b","content":"b2"}]' (length=59)`

How to get correct json format

**PHP**

I use Laravel as framework, and this field named data

```
public function setDataAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['data'] = json_encode($value);
}

public function getDataAttribute($value) {
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

Comment: What's your PHP code?

Comment: Looks fine. What's the error thrown by `json_decode()`?

Comment: No error, it just convert it into string

Comment: Shouldn't you add `true` to the json decode? So this: `json_decode($value, true)`?

Comment: It is valid JSON string. What is your expectation?

Comment: If you call `json_decode()` on that string in PHP it should return an object. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: It seems that you have stringified it twice, so you have a string that contains JSON that represents a string that contains the JSON for your object. The solution would of course be to not stringify it twice, but that's not done in the part of code that you have shown.

Comment: I want to it convert to object and I will use foreach to show the correct data, but it turns to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted `json string` in `result` field so you will not need to `json_code` before saving data in database

```
public function setDataAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['data'] = $value;
}
```

it would be work fine..

This is json encode data :

```
 '[{"title":"a","content":"a2"},{"title":"b","content":"b2"}]'
```

And again encode json string

```
json_encode('[{"title":"a","content":"a2"},{"title":"b","content":"b2"}]');
```

Then result

```
"[{\"title\":\"a\",\"content\":\"a2\"},{\"title\":\"b\",\"content\":\"b2\"}]"
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, that's mean I need to do json_decode in view to run foreach for keep correct value in result input